# Why am I getting errors saying column doesn't exist when I try to create more than three columns in a table in SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here is my code. I'm getting an error saying table users has no column named street.

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.openOrCreateDatabase("ee",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name VARCHAR, age INT(3),id INT(3),house VARCHAR,street VARCHAR)");
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO users (name,age,id,house,street) VALUES ('ROB',34,33,'home','street')");
Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users",null);
int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
int ageIndex = c.getColumnIndex("age");
int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
int houseIndex = c.getColumnIndex("house");
int streetIndex = c.getColumnIndex("street");

c.moveToFirst();
while (c!=null){
    Log.i("Name",c.getString(nameIndex));
    Log.i("Age",Integer.toString(c.getInt(ageIndex)));
    Log.i("id",Integer.toString(c.getInt(idIndex)));
    Log.i("house",c.getString(houseIndex));
    Log.i("street",c.getString(streetIndex));

    c.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: Did you add 'street' column in later on ? For example there were only 3 columns and then later on you added the 4th column 'street' ?

Comment: No I created the table with all four at the same time

Comment: exception + stacktrace would help

Comment: Do you get the same exception when you uninstall the application and reinstall the application again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message clearly indicates that the **street** column doesn't exist. There is nothing wrong with the CREATE SQL so it is highly likely that you have modified this statement since originally creating the table in which case the `IF NOT EXISTS` causes the execution of the table creation to not be undertaken (it would fail anyway as the table exists).

If you have no data that needs to be preserved then the simplest fix is to either delete the App's data or to uninstall the App and rerun.

I can confirm that your code is sound as such (see note) and when run after doing the above produces/results in :-

```
03-31 20:47:12.442 1142-1142/? I/Name: ROB
03-31 20:47:12.442 1142-1142/? I/Age: 34
03-31 20:47:12.442 1142-1142/? I/id: 33
03-31 20:47:12.442 1142-1142/? I/house: home
03-31 20:47:12.442 1142-1142/? I/street: street
```

- **Note** after this you App will crash as you are incorrectly trying to traverse the Cursor. see below for fix.

If you do have data that needs to be preserved then you could use :-

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.openOrCreateDatabase("ee",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name VARCHAR, age INT(3),id INT(3),house VARCHAR,street VARCHAR)");
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN street VARCHAR"); //<<<< ADDED
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO users (name,age,id,house,street) VALUES ('ROB',34,33,'home','street')");
....... rest of your code

}
```

However using the above would fail if used a second time as the column would then exist. So the add line should be removed after the first run.

### Cursor Traversal Fix

In you code after obtaining the Cursor you move to the first row using `moveToFirst` followed by a check to see if the Cursor is null.

This is open to failure as a Cursor returned from an SQLiteDatabase method will NEVER be null. It is a useless check. If a Cursor has no rows then it will have a count (the Cursor's `getCount` method returns an integer with the number of rows, which could be 0) Instead you should be checking the return from the `moveToFirst` it will be true if the move to the first row could be made, if there are no rows then false would be returned.

You could use `if (c.moveToFirst()) { .... do your stuff }`.

You also have an unchecked `moveToNext`, again true is returned if the move could be made else false. So if you have 1 row after the first you will get a failure `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1`. This is because when the next iteration of the loop happens the line `int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");` is attemtping to get the 2nd row (first row is Index 0) when a 2nd row doesn't exist.

- i.e. The message is saying you are trying to access the 2nd row when there is only 1 row.

I'd suggest replacing :-

```
c.moveToFirst();
while (c!=null){
    Log.i("Name",c.getString(nameIndex));
    Log.i("Age",Integer.toString(c.getInt(ageIndex)));
    Log.i("id",Integer.toString(c.getInt(idIndex)));
    Log.i("house",c.getString(houseIndex));
    Log.i("street",c.getString(streetIndex));

    c.moveToNext();
}
```

with

```
while (c.moveToNext())
    Log.i("Name",c.getString(nameIndex));
    Log.i("Age",Integer.toString(c.getInt(ageIndex)));
    Log.i("id",Integer.toString(c.getInt(idIndex)));
    Log.i("house",c.getString(houseIndex));
    Log.i("street",c.getString(streetIndex));
}
```

#### Note

- As it stands you code will, upon each run add a new row, with the same data, to the database e.g. the output from a 2nd run would be :-

  `03-31 21:12:01.635 1279-1279/? I/Name: ROB
  03-31 21:12:01.635 1279-1279/? I/Age: 34
  03-31 21:12:01.635 1279-1279/? I/id: 33
  03-31 21:12:01.635 1279-1279/? I/house: home
  03-31 21:12:01.635 1279-1279/? I/street: street
  03-31 21:12:01.635 1279-1279/? I/Name: ROB
  03-31 21:12:01.635 1279-1279/? I/Age: 34
  03-31 21:12:01.635 1279-1279/? I/id: 33
  03-31 21:12:01.635 1279-1279/? I/house: home
  03-31 21:12:01.635 1279-1279/? I/street: street`

Answer (score 0):

Thought its difficult to guess the error here without proper stack trace. However, I think the problem is the table has not recreated after the `street` column has added. I think the initial table was containing four columns only which are `name, age, id, house`. Then the `street` column has been added. However, the table was not created again as the create table command consists, `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`.

So I would like to suggest you a fresh install after uninstalling your current version of the application in your device and then check if the same error occurs.

However, you might consider doing it in another way as well if you are using `SQLiteOpenHelper` to open your database, which will not require uninstalling the application. Just drop the table in your `onUpgrade` function and each time you run the application in your device, just update the database version, so that the previous database table is deleted and it acts like a new one.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP table users");   
}
```

Comment: There is no onUpgrade as a subclass of SQLIteOpenHelper hasn't been used. The database is being opened directly as per `SQLiteDatabase database = this.openOrCreateDatabase("ee",MODE_PRIVATE,null);`